# Google map api markers, sql and xml

Tags: php, xml, google-maps

I'm using Google's map api to plot some markers on a map. I followed the docs on how to do this with a database by using xml as an intermediary. When my site is loaded, a php file is loaded echo the xml of the database for the map api to plot.

I am wondering, at the moment it's fine because they're aren't many rows... however if I had loads of rows in the database would this php file take a while to run as it has to echo all the xml. Would it be better to create a static xml file with the info, then whenever somebody adds something to the database, it also adds a new element to the xml file, and if so would it not make sense to ONLY have an xml file to manage it all.

Hopefully you can understand what I mean and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This question is borderline opinion-based but still answerable in terms of software architecture and software engineering trade-offs. You should choose the simplest solution that can possibly meet your requirements. You have not listed any requirements that would necessitate having a database in the solution, other than, *it came with the sample code*. So go ahead and remove it.